# How can I forward a regional IP to a global forwarding IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ip, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

Tonight, my client is going to be on a high-profile television show to pitch his business. I created their API and had it running on a small server on Google Cloud Platform with a static IP on the instance since that was all that we needed.

Now I am trying to scale it for the inevitable traffic, I'm moving to a load balancer and multiple, scalable instances. I thought I could use the IP address from the instance and transfer it to the load balancer. But the load balancer requires a global forwarding IP, and the IP address of the instance is only regional.

For some reason, the mobile developers hardcoded their URLs to the IP address and not the domain name. It's too late in the day for them to resubmit the app code, so I need a way to forward the regional IP to the global forwarding IP that the load balancer takes.

Could I do this through Google Cloud Platform? Or should I set this up through the domain name provider?

I realize that this may break some rules on SO, but I only need the answer for today, the question can come down tomorrow if it does break rules.

Comment: What is a regional IP address? There are two IPs: IPv4 and IPv6, both of which have global addressing, but neither has regional addressing.

Comment: I think these are restrictions in place set by Google. My global forwarding IP takes the form 35.190.0.0/16 and my regional IP takes the form  104.154.0.0/16. The load balancer can only accept the global forwarding IP. GCP won't allow me to assign the regional IP to the load balancer.

Comment: I don't think you can load balance this with the current architecture. You need change the app to support a configurable host name, and not a static IP.  Did they really code that with a fixed ip!?

Comment: What is the protocol the mobile app uses to communicate to the server?  http/s?

Comment: From the perspective of IPv4, any address in the `104.154.0.0/16` range _is_ a global IP address. You probably want to ask this question on [sf], instead.

Comment: @RonMaupin the "regional"-ality or "global"-ness is, as you point out, not really an attribute of the IP address, but rather of the address pool to which GC has assigned them.  This is a concept they use in Google Cloud, which dictates how an address can be mapped/used [on that platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/)... i.e. addresses from Regional pools vs. Global pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot today may be to increase the memory/cpu of the current machine type and/or use something like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) to proxy requests from the instance to the load balanced fleet.

> It is possible to use nginx as a very efficient HTTP load balancer to
>   distribute traffic to several application servers and to improve
>   performance, scalability and reliability of web applications with
>   nginx.

I would do both: increase instance capacity and try an Nginx proxy on that instance. You will still have a single point of failure, but would be able to handle greater capacity.

Essentially this configuration will forward requests from the instance (the regional ip) to your GCP load balancer (the global ip)

Comment: Yes exactly. Except your upstream would be the load balancer, which then would actually distribute load. This assumes it is all http/s traffic. Is it?